# Add statements to serverless "KeyPolicy" on KMS Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a serverless application, which creates a KMS Resource:

```
# serverless.yml 1
resources:
  Resources:
    SomeLambdaRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    AnotherLambdaRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    TheKey:
      Type: AWS::KMS::Key
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        Description: The key
        Enabled: true
        KeyPolicy:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Sid: Allow use of the key
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS:
                  - Fn::GetAtt: [SomeLambdaRole, Arn]
                  - Fn::GetAtt: [AnotherLambdaRole, Arn]
              Action:
                - 'kms:Encrypt'
                - 'kms:Decrypt'
                - 'kms:ReEncrypt'
                - 'kms:GenerateDataKey*'
              Resource: '*'
```

From another serverless application where some roles are created, I want to give these new roles the same permissions that `SomeLambdaRole` and `AnotherLambdaRole` have on the "TheKey" Resource

```
# serverless.yml 2
resources:
  Resources:
    YetAnotherLambdaRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
# Do something to let this role have the same permission as "SomeLambdaRole" and "AnotherLambdaRole" for the "TheKey" Resource
```

Is this possible or should I try another approach?

Comment: any follow ups?

Comment: Hey @Ashwin, I don't remember exactly, but I think I ended up refactoring the usage of a KMS key for this. Couldn't find a way to update the key principals without re deploying the app where this resource is created